# Configure InnoDB / WAMP / Windows 7

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, wamp

I'm using WampServer 2.1 on Windows 7 SP1 and I'm not being able to set up MySQL to use InnoDB tables.

Here is part of my configs ( in config.inc.php ):

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapass';
```

I already created a database named phpmyadmin, the user phpmyadmin (and priviliges for SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE and INSERT on its DB) with password pmapass.

I already ran the create_tables.sql script and checked the tables name and they are all correct. However, still getting this error in phpmyadmin:

> The additional features for working with linked tables have been deactivated. To find out why click here.

And this is the diagnose:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] ...    OK
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] ... not OK [ Documentation ]
General relation features: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] ...   not OK [ Documentation ]
Display Features: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] ... not OK [ Documentation ]
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] ...    not OK [ Documentation ]
Creation of PDFs: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] ...  not OK [ Documentation ]
Displaying Column Comments: Disabled
Browser transformation: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] ...    not OK [ Documentation ]
Bookmarked SQL query: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] ...  not OK [ Documentation ]
SQL history: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] ...  not OK [ Documentation ]
Designer: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] ... not OK [ Documentation ]
Tracking: Disabled
```

Don't know if has anything to do with the user logged in but tried with both root and phpmyadmin , without any success. Already deleted all the cache, cookies, etc... tried with IE9, FF6 and Chrome13 (read some people saying that it does not work in chrome). Also restarted the server and nothing...

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, when I booted up my computer today all the configs were OK except the last one. I was missing this one:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
```

Had to delete all cache and cookies like twice or three times! (using Chrome and FF6)